# SSH session with Python subprocess.Popen doesn't display Bash prompt

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm using Popen to ssh to a remote machine, and I could ssh (with manual password entry) and give commands and get response strings.

But I could not see the Bash prompt string. I could not find a reason why Bash prompt string alone is missing from response strings.

Can anyone please throw some light on this?

My program:

```
ph = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', remote, port],
                               stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                               stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                               universal_newlines=True,
                               bufsize=1)
fcntl.fcntl(ph.stdout.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
fcntl.fcntl(ph.stderr.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

def ReadOut (cmd) :
    tmo = 2
    while tmo >= 0 :
        try :
            line = ph.stdout.readline ()
            print (line,end="")
            if not line :
                tmo -= 1
                time.sleep (1)
        except IOError :
            break

ph.stdin.write("ls .\n")
ReadOut ("ls .")
ph.stdin.write("uptime\n")
ReadOut ("uptime")
```

Response strings for ls and uptime commands from above code (Bash prompt and commands input to ssh are missing):

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
examples.desktop
minicom.log
Music
Pictures
Public
snap
Templates
Videos
 15:37:13 up  5:09,  1 user,  load average: 0.16, 0.03, 0.01
```

Thank you.

EDIT 1:
If I add same readline() logic for stderr like I did for stdout, an unknown command string results - "-bash: line 1: unknown_cmd: command not found"

Comment: Does adding `-t` to the ssh command help?

Comment: I think the prompt is written to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Try `stderr = subprocess.STDOUT` instead of `stderr = subprocess.PIPE` in the `subprocess.Popen` call, to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: @TurePålsson Tried with '-t'. Didn't work.

Comment: @JohanL Tried with stderr as suggested (and had to remove fcntl call on ph.stderr as it throws error). But I could see no difference except warning 'Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal'.
One more thing - I had done ph.stderr.readline() to print any stderr messages previously in the code in ReadOut(), but it's all same expect the warning about pseudo-terminal.

Comment: why dont you use paramiko? http://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/client.html

Comment: @balderman Yes. I started looking at existing modules like paramiko, fabric, etc. They're my backup. I want to try it out without these first to gain more understanding as I'm new to python.